# What's the best way to get full ICU + CLDR support in React Native?

Tags: react-native, internationalization, icu, cldr

Are there any OSS tools that provide full ICU-level support for CLDR data in react native? We're currently using react-native-i18n and I just don't know where the data comes from.

What I'm most interested in right now is formatting numbers and currency across currency types/locales